# How can I merge an arbitrary number of sources in Akka stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have `n` sources that I'd like to merge by priority in Akka streams. I'm basing my implementation on the [GraphMergePrioritiziedSpec](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream-tests/src/test/scala/akka/stream/scaladsl/GraphMergePrioritizedSpec.scala#L139), in which three prioritized sources are merged. I attempted to abstract away the number of `Source`s with the following:

```
import akka.NotUsed
import akka.stream.{ClosedShape, Graph, Materializer}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{GraphDSL, MergePrioritized, RunnableGraph, Sink, Source}
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory

class SourceMerger(
  sources: Seq[Source[java.io.Serializable, NotUsed]],
  priorities: Seq[Int],
  private val sink: Sink[java.io.Serializable, _]
) {

  require(sources.size == priorities.size, "Each source should have a priority")

  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  private def partial(
    sources: Seq[Source[java.io.Serializable, NotUsed]],
    priorities: Seq[Int],
    sink: Sink[java.io.Serializable, _]
  ): Graph[ClosedShape, NotUsed] = GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>

      val merge = b.add(MergePrioritized[java.io.Serializable](priorities))

      sources.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (s, i) =>
        s.shape.out ~> merge.in(i)
      }

      merge.out ~> sink
      ClosedShape
  }

  def merge(
    sources: Seq[Source[java.io.Serializable, NotUsed]],
    priorities: Seq[Int],
    sink: Sink[java.io.Serializable, _]
  ): RunnableGraph[NotUsed] = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(partial(sources, priorities, sink))

  def run()(implicit mat: Materializer): NotUsed = merge(sources, priorities, sink).run()(mat)
}
```

However, I get an error when running the following stub:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.{ActorMaterializer, Materializer}
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Sink, Source}
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpecLike}
import akka.testkit.TestKit

import scala.collection.immutable.Iterable

class SourceMergerSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("SourceMerger")) with WordSpecLike with Matchers {

  implicit val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  "A SourceMerger" should {
    "merge by priority" in {

      val priorities: Seq[Int] = Seq(1,2,3)

      val highPriority = Iterable("message1", "message2", "message3")
      val mediumPriority = Iterable("message4", "message5", "message6")
      val lowPriority = Iterable("message7", "message8", "message9")

      val source1 = Source[String](highPriority)
      val source2 = Source[String](mediumPriority)
      val source3 = Source[String](lowPriority)

      val sources = Seq(source1, source2, source3)

      val subscriber = Sink.seq[java.io.Serializable]

      val merger = new SourceMerger(sources, priorities, subscriber)

      merger.run()

      source1.runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
    }
  }

}
```

The relevant stacktrace is here:

```
[StatefulMapConcat.out] is already connected
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [StatefulMapConcat.out] is already connected
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL$Builder.addEdge(Graph.scala:1304)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL$Implicits$CombinerBase$class.$tilde$greater(Graph.scala:1431)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.GraphDSL$Implicits$PortOpsImpl.$tilde$greater(Graph.scala:1521)
    at SourceMerger$$anonfun$partial$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SourceMerger.scala:26)
    at SourceMerger$$anonfun$partial$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SourceMerger.scala:25)
```

It seems that the error comes from this:

```
sources.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (s, i) =>
  s.shape.out ~> merge.in(i)
}
```

Is it possible to merge an arbitrary number of `Source`s in Akka streams Graph DSL? If so, why isn't my attempt successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primary Problem with Code Example**

One big issue with the code snippet provided in the question is that `source1` is connected to the `Sink` from the `merge` call and the `Sink.foreach(println)`.  The same `Source` cannot be connected to multiple Sinks without an [intermediate fan-out element](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-dynamic.html#dynamic-fan-in-and-fan-out-with-mergehub-broadcasthub-and-partitionhub).

Removing the `Sink.foreach(println)` may solve your problem outright.

**Simplified Design**

The merging can be simplified based on the fact that all messages from a particular `Source` have the same priority.  This means that you can sort the sources by their respective priority and then concatenate them all together:

```
private def partial(sources: Seq[Source[java.io.Serializable, NotUsed]],
                    priorities: Seq[Int],
                    sink: Sink[java.io.Serializable, _]): RunnableGraph[NotUsed] = 
   sources.zip(priorities)
          .sortWith(_._2 < _._2)
          .map(_._1)
          .reduceOption(_ ++ _)
          .getOrElse(Source.empty[java.io.Serializable])
          .to(sink)
```

Comment: This seems really nice. I particularly like the avoidance of the `MergePrioritized`. Using your construct, would it be true that if I have a combined source which has a current view of all low-priority messages, a high priority message would be pushed to the front when it comes in? I'm trying to formulate a test for that, but I'm pretty new with Akka's streaming API.

Comment: @erip Because my implementation uses concatenation the higher priority source would have to be exhausted, end-of-stream, before any elements were pulled from the lower priority sources.  Therefore, the scenario you described would not be possible...

Comment: Hmmm. Is it possible at all?

Comment: @erip No.  In your example code, `source1` would have to be completely exhausted before any elements from `source2` were processed.  Until `source1` sends an end-of-stream signal `source2` would be dormant.

Comment: Akka stream doesn't support merging infinite stream; i.e., this source is empty, but not terminated -- consume from the next source? Hmm.

Comment: @erip NOTE: I am not merging, I am concatenating, e.g. `++`.  Therefore, `infiniteStream ++ otherStream = infiniteStream` since `otherStream` will never be processed...

Comment: Ah! Yes, I understand now. Given I didn't explain the problem I was trying to solve properly, I think your answer is best -- not quite what I intended, but that's my fault. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code runs without the error if I replace

```
  sources.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (s, i) =>
    s.shape.out ~> merge.in(i)
  }
```

with

```
  sources.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (s, i) =>
    s ~> merge.in(i)
  }
```

I admit I'm not quite sure why! At any rate, `s.shape` is a `StatefulMapConcat` and that's the point where it's complaining about the out port already being connected. The problem occurs even if you only pass a single source, so the arbitrary number isn't the problem.

Comment: I do not know how I missed this!